# Trying to Unstake a COIN without success

Tags: unstake

I am trying to unstake EFX tokens from the dashboard.effect.ai/stake website but keep getting an error that says "Transaction error, Error: transaction net usage is too high: 216>0".

I went ahead and added RAM by staking 45 EOS but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas as to what I need to do to get this out the staking process?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There are three resources on EOS: NET, CPU, and RAM. The error message you described specifically says that you have insufficient NET resources on your account.

Rather than explaining resource management, it may be more helpful for me to simply mention some community tools that do resource management for you automatically:

- The **Anchor** authenticator (https://greymass.com/en/anchor/) will let you simply pay tiny transaction fees.
- The **Charm** service (https://arm.chintai.io/) will automatically purchase resources for you if you get too low.